# How to implement LRP on "innvestigate" module

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, xai

I have trained a CNN model on images of malaria disease, I have about 96% accuracy on this model, I want to implement a LRP on this model to understand what are the features of the image that trigger that classification.

```
# All necessary imports 

model = load_model("path/to/model.h5")
image = "path/to/test.png"
analyzer = innvestigate.create_analyzser(name="lrp", model=model)
attributions = analyzer.analyze(image)
```

I get the following error :
'''ValueError: Need LRP rule(s)'''

I tried going to the documentation of the LRP module, it had some information about some methods in that class, but I couldn't understand majority of it. Would be great help if someone could explain to me <3